# How to stop elements from flickering when the page reloads in Google Chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, css, navbar

When I reload the page all the elements that are using a custom font flicker. It only happens in the Google Chrome browser.

Is there a way to make them not flicker just like, for example, the elements in the navigation bar from https://getbootstrap.com/?

HTML

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul>
            <li>Item 1</li>
            <li>Item 2</li>
            <li>Item 3</li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Montserrat";
    src: url("static/Montserrat-Regular.ttf");
}

* {
    font-family: "Montserrat";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have caching turned off in your browser or on your server per chance?

It's expected for it to do it once when the file loads for the first time or when you've cleared your caches, but not every time.

It sounds like the font is updating after the font file has had a chance to load, but it's hard to tell without more information. Could you link the full code?

Comment: I don't have caching turned off. This is the entire code :)

Comment: I just noticed that it only happens in Chrome...